# How do I determine what capacitor to use for motor driver decoupling?

Tags: capacitor, motor-controller, decoupling-capacitor

I am designing a control module for model trains that uses an ESP32 to control everything. Due to the nature of this, I have very strict dimension and thermal requirements. (Must be able to run for several hours without overheating, no air circulation, must be operable between 12 and 20v AC or DC, 500mA for the motor, etc.) While designing the schematic, I discovered that my chosen motor driver's datasheet states the need for an electrolytic capacitor across VS and GND.

> An electrolytic and 100nF ceramic capacitors are recommended to be placed as close as possible to the VS supply pin of the device for improved EMC performance in the high and low frequency band. The electrolytic capacitor must be dimensioned to prevent the VS voltage from exceeding the absolute maximum rating. In addition, decoupling capacitors are recommended on the VDD supply pin.

(Section 5.1: General power Supply)

I need to be able to keep the total PCB thickness under 8mm in order for it to fit in many model locomotives, so most electrolytics are out. This brings me to the two questions I have here: Do I strictly need an electrolytic capacitor in addition to the 100nF ceramic or can I use something like another ceramic capacitor? What capacitance do I need?

I have attached an image of my schematic so far and here is a link to the datasheet for the motor driver: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE94103EP-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626176435901618f005622681e

[image: Schematic]

Comment: you can get 10uf ceramics for cheap, using more than one if needed.

Comment: @dandavis so then I *don't* need electrolytics specifically?

Comment: no, electrolytics have high capacity going for them, but in almost all other measures ceramics are better. Since electrolytics are the lower end, it's typically more a case of you _can_ use them than you _must_ use them. Other types of capacitors are sometimes a _must_ but i can't recall ever seeing electrolytics needed specifically; just the size/cost they offer.

Comment: Ok then. That just leaves me with the question of how much capacitance I need.

Comment: they show a 22uf, but it is optional if your supply voltage isn't higher than 20dc. 10 or 20 uf should be fine, use a voltage regulator like an lm7812 if you are anywhere close to 20v, which feeds the driver 12v and eliminates the specification need. still, a 10uf isn't a bad idea to help keep things clean.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis